# Divide long string into 5 container but don't break words

Tags: php, html

I have a long text in php database and I want to divide it in 5 `<div>` without breaking sentences and words. If my long text dived in 4 `<div>` then remaining `<div>` not display.

Here I attach sample to display long text in 2 `<div>`

[image]

my fetching data coding sample

```
<?php   
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM bookrecord where status='a' ") or die("Could not retrieve image: " .mysqli_error($conn));

if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        extract($row);      
        ?>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="projects-agile-grid-info">
                    <div class="projects-grid-caption">                                     
                        <p><?php echo $row['book-description'];?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Eh... Expected output?

Comment: I do not think you should have: extract($row);

Comment: sentences should not be broken too?

Comment: Why not split sentences (you'd have to determine if you have a good pattern to do this), and print sentences until it fills the box?